# Finding linux users with a bash script

Tags: linux, bash

i am newbie in bash-scripting and linux. I want to write a script to get a username from the terminal and say whether that username is on the passwd or not. i wrote and tried below script but it doesn't work. help me that what i can do.

```
users = cat /etc/passwd
echo User_Name
cat users | grep User_Name
if [ User_Name in users ];
then
    echo "User_Name FOUND"
else
    echo "User NOT FOUND!"
fi
```

how i can define a variable to read a string from termnial.

Comment: The key is -- however you do it, you must distinguish between, etc.. `"ann"` and `"anna"` so you must compare against the entire first field in `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: @SiGnoR : Your first line runs a command `users` with three parameters (`=`, `cat` and `/etc/passwd`). See [here](https://www.linuxvasanth.com/create-assign-values-variables-bash-shell-scripting/) how to **create** a variable. Your third command asks for outputting a file named `users`. See [here](https://guide.bash.academy/expansions/) for how to **use** a variable. Finally you don't  have any statement in your code which would read a user name from the terminal.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To print and read an argument from terminal, you should use **echo** and then use read commane and then call it with dollar-sign, finally the script know what you want.
for example:

```
echo "Enter UserName: "
read User_Name
```

here is the correct form of your code:

```
echo "Enter the Username: "
read User_Name
cut -f 1 -d: /etc/passwd | grep -q $User_Name
if [ $? -eq 0 ];
then
    echo "User $User_Name FOUND"
else
    echo "User NOT FOUND!"
fi
```

---

**Tips:**

```
cut -f 1 -d  #cut the first column of the passwd list
grep -q # find username and do  not  write  anything  to  standard   output in terminal.

if [ $? -eq 0 ] #in linux terminal when we want to know whether the previous command is executed correctly we use $? and the output must be 0. and - eq means equal to 0. and when we use that, it means if previos command (grep the username) executed correctly and the username was found, then run next step and print it found.
```

Comment: See what happens when user presses Enter without entering a non-empty username.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk yes, i see that your solution is true. but he doesn't ask for a non-empty username at all.

Comment: The script is broken, don't use it. It doesn't correctly check for a
full username. Just press `t` and it will say that user `t` exists
because there is `t` in `root` even if there is no such user on the
system. You have to use `^user:` form to do it correctly.

Comment: OP asks for help in writing a script and it should be your responsibility to deliver a script that would work in all cases. How can you be sure that users of the script will never pass an empty username?

Comment: Or `^user$` if you use `cut` first.

Answer (score 2):

Your script could look like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -rp "Enter user name: " user_name
do
    if [ -z "$user_name" ]
    then
        echo "Enter a non-empty username"    
        continue
    fi

    if grep -q "^$user_name:" /etc/passwd
    then
        echo "$user_name FOUND"
        exit 0
    else
        echo "$user_name NOT FOUND!" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

Comment: thanks very much i tried and it worked great. but i can't understand below of "while true"

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Can you be clearer? Which part don't you understand?

Comment: The `while true;` can be replaced with `while read -rp "Enter user name: " user_name ; do` also you can probably send the error message to `stderr`  e.g. `echo "$user_name NOT FOUND!" >&2` and add an `exit 1` after that message., just my 2 cents.

Comment: Using `grep -q` will prevent outputting the entire line from `/etc/passwd` (or redirect to `> /dev/nul`)

Comment: @Jetchisel: I applied your `>& stderr` and `exit 1` suggestion, thx. WRT to `while read` - do you mean you'd make this script ask about input continuously until SIGINT?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, It has the same effect as your `while true; do` , just a suggestion nothing serious about it.

Comment: @Jetchisel: ok, don't be so shy :) I'm not sure if this is the same - currently my scripts asks for input in `while` loop and after exiting from it it checks if user exists and exits.

Comment: Yes, your second example will not stop until the input is not empty, you will have the same effect/result with what I have suggested.

Comment: @Jetchisel: ok, I think I got what you mean. I modified your suggestion slightly and moved everything to a single loop with an explicit `exit 0` when username is found.

Comment: Ok, I'm glad you have accepted my suggestion, I have my own answer to this by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my take on this question. Using `getent` to search user in the file `/etc/passwd`

If you just want to check if a user exists.

```
getent passwd "$username"
```

That should print the name (and all info in the [Gecos Field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field)) of the user  if it does exists, and return with zero `0` status which means true. Otherwise non-zero, see the manual for the meaning of different status.

---

Now that we know that information at hand we can use the `if-statement`

```
if getent passwd "$username"; then
  echo "$username found."
else
  echo "$username not found." >&2
fi
```

---

Redirect the output to `/dev/null` if that is not the desired result, or if you're just after the exit/return status of the test.

```
if getent passwd "$username" >/dev/null; then
  echo "$username found."
else
  echo "$username not found." >&2
fi
```

---

To add that to a full blown script.

```
#!/bin/sh

check_user() {
  printf '%s' "Enter user name: "
  read -r user_name
  case $user_name in
    '') printf '%s\n' "You have not entered anything!" >&2  ##: If empty input.
     return 1;;
  esac
  if getent passwd "$user_name" >/dev/null; then ##: getent has no -q option unfortunately.
    printf '%s\n' "$user_name FOUND"
    return 0
  else
    printf '%s\n' "$user_name NOT FOUND!" >&2
    return 1
  fi
}

##: Continue the loop until a match in `/etc/passwd` was given.
until check_user; do
  printf 'Please try again!\n' >&2  ##: Send message to stderr and loop again.
done
```

---

Instead of redirecting to `/dev/null` you can save the output of `getent` in a variable using [Command Substituion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03) and use that value, plus a little bit of [Parameter Expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02).

```
check_user() {
  printf '%s' "Enter user name: "
  read -r user_name
  case $user_name in
    '') printf '%s\n' "You have not entered anything!" >&2
     return 1;;
  esac
  if user=$(getent passwd "$user_name"); then
    printf '%s\n' "${user%%:*} FOUND"  ##: Print only the username using P.E.
    return 0
  else
    printf '%s\n' "${user:-"$user_name"} NOT FOUND" >&2  ##: If the value of "$user" is empty (No match found by getent)
    return 1
  fi
}

until check_user; do
  printf 'Please try again!\n' >&2
done
```

- The `until` loop will continue until it receives a `0` return status.
- See `getent(1)` aka `man 1 getent`
- See [Bash Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)
- See [Posix Parameter Expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02)
- Tested on both `GNU Linux` and `FreeBSD`

Comment: 1. Why are you checking if `user_name` is empty with `case`? Are there shells in which `test -z` is not implemented? [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) mentions it. 2. There are 3 warnings from `shellcheck`, it would be good if you fixed them.

Comment: `bash` however is less portable, not present on FreeBSD by default for example.

Comment: Not always possible if you're not root (although in this particular case you wouldn't even have to install bash to `/bin` because you use `/usr/bin/env` and you can always run `bash script`). There are also some Linux systems that come with Busybox/Toybox that also do not provide Bash, most commonly in the embedded use.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Right, I think shellcheck is happy now with `POSIX sh` syntax. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Yes, shellcheck is happy but you didn't answer my 1st question.

Comment: Ah. you mean the case? Well Nothing to serious about that, `case` can test for empty pattern too, I don't see anything wrong with that.

Comment: Yes. It's not wrong, it just looks weird as if other `cases` were missing.

Comment: Well, you already have the `-z` test so I'm doing the `case` :-)

Comment: Don't get me wrong, shell syntax does not look sane, so I don't expect anything non-weird will come out of the shell syntax...

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk The questioner literally asked for an answer in Bash on Linux.

Comment: @solidsnack: some comments were deleted (this is possible on SE) and if you looked into post history you'd see that post's author changed shebang from sh to bash and again and we discussed that Bash is not present on FreeBSD that post's author said they tested their script on and suggested that if bash is missing users could just install it which is not always possible

Answer (score 0):

To read a value as a user input, you can use the "read" command.

```
read User_Name


echo "User is ${User_Name}"
```

For convenience, most scripts use ALLCAPS on the variable names for shell scripting.

Also consider passing this value as a parameter into your script. It's readable as "$1" for a single parameter.

Hint1: You don't need to store the whole file in memory just for this check.

Hint2: To find if a user is present in the passwd file, you should check for the first column only of that file and try a match.

Hint3: If you want to use the grep command, it will return success when there's a match and failure when there's not match.

The code below would also work for the task

```
#!/bin/bash
read WHO; 
grep "^${WHO}:" /etc/passwd 2>/dev/null >/dev/null && echo "found" || echo "not found"
```

Answer (score 0):

We use `read` to get input from the user at the terminal.
In the below solution, we use [POSIX `id`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/id.html) (present on BSDs as well as Linux) to determine if the user exists or not.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit -o pipefail -o nounset


function interactive_check_if_user_exists {
    local username output

    read -p 'Username to check: ' -r username

    if output="$(id -u "$username" 2>&1)"
    then
        echo "Found \`$username\` (uid: $output)" >&2
    else
        local code=$?
        if [[ $code -eq 1 ]]
        then
            echo "User \`$username\` is not present on this system." >&2
        else
            echo "Unexpected error occurred: $output" >&2
            return "$code"
        fi
    fi
}

interactive_check_if_user_exists
```